# Specify DeadLetterQueue for redelivered messages in MessageDrivenBean

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, message-driven-bean

I've create a MDB that reads messages from ActiveMQ

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageReaderEJB",
    activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",
                    propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                    propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                    propertyValue = "archive.>")

    })

@Slf4j
public class ArchiveMessageListenerBean implements MessageListener {
   ...
   @Override
   public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
   ...
   }
   ...
}
```

and my glassfish-ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish 
Application Server 3.1 EJB 3.1//EN"
    "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-ejb-jar_3_1-1.dtd">
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
<enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
        <ejb-name>MessageReaderEJB</ejb-name>
        <mdb-connection-factory>
            <jndi-name>jms/jms.connectionFactory</jndi-name>
        </mdb-connection-factory>
        <mdb-resource-adapter>
            <resource-adapter-mid>ActiveMQ-Resource-Adapter-5.14.1</resource-adapter-mid>
        </mdb-resource-adapter>

    </ejb>
</enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

If there is an exception thrown in onMessage() there are some redeliveries and after max. redeliveries the message will be send to ActiveMQ.DLQ.
How can I configure that the message will be send to my.error.queue instead of ActiveMQ.DLQ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only specify a specific dead letter queue prefix for a given queue or topic. 
You can use Camel if you want to route messages from DLQ to another one based on JMSDestination messages  header.

> The broker transmits the default delivery policy that he prefers to a
>   client connection in his BrokerInfo command packet. But the client can
>   override the policy settings by using the
>   **ActiveMQConnection.getRedeliveryPolicy()** method:

```
RedeliveryPolicy policy = connection.getRedeliveryPolicy();
policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(500);
policy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);
```

> Once a message's redelivery attempts exceeds the maximumRedeliveries
>   configured for the Redelivery Policy, a "Poison ACK" is sent back to
>   the broker letting him know that the message was considered a poison
>   pill. The Broker then takes the message and sends it to a Dead Letter
>   Queue so that it can be analyzed later on.
>
> The default Dead Letter Queue in ActiveMQ is called ActiveMQ.DLQ; all
>   un-deliverable messages will get sent to this queue and this can be
>   difficult to manage. So, you can set an individualDeadLetterStrategy
>   in the destination policy map of the activemq.xml configuration file,
>   which allows you to specify a specific dead letter queue prefix for a
>   given queue or topic. You can apply this strategy using wild card if
>   you like so that all queues get their own dead-letter queue, as is
>   shown in the example below.

```
<broker>
     <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry queue=">">
              <deadLetterStrategy>
                   <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
              </deadLetterStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
</broker>
```

> See the Redelivery Policy section for some more detail on the policy
>   options.

http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Comment: Thanks for help! With "<policyEntry queue="archive.>">" I can configure what I want!